# F# casting anonymous type to struct record

Tags: f#

I am having simple anonymous object collection from c# database service (I can look into it but can not modify the code) that looks like:

```
entities[InfoKey].Add(
    new
    {
        id = (int)result[0],
        mpvId = Convert.ToUInt32(result[1]),
        date = ((DateTime)result[2]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
        systemId = Convert.ToUInt32(result[3]),
        name = (string)result[4]
    });
```

Now in f# service where I can actually do something I want this to be cast to record (so i can make some actual operations on it), so I created something like:

```
type private StatisticsInfoCursor = {
    Id: int;
    MpvId : uint32;
    Date : string; 
    SystemId : uint32;
    Name : string;
}
```

And casting operation looks, or it should be simple:

```
let infoCursor = 
    try
        rawData.[StatisticsInfoRepository.InfoKey] 
        |> Seq.map 
            (fun v -> 
                let unboxObject = v |> unbox // THIS COUSES EXCEPTION
                {Id = unboxObject.Id; MpvCabinetId = unboxObject.MpvCabinetId; Date = unboxObject.Date; SystemId = unboxObject.SystemId; Name = unboxObject.Name})
    with 
        ex -> raise ex
```

And a simple call:

```
for data in infoCursor do
    printf "%i - %A" data.Id data.Date
()
```

But all I am getting is

> Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType19`5[System.Int32,System.UInt32,System.String,System.UInt32,System.String]' to type 'StatisticsInfoCursor'.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I made something like this using reflection:

```
let GetPropertyValue (object : obj) propertyName =
   let objectType = object.GetType()
   let propertyInfo = objectType.GetProperty propertyName
   propertyInfo.GetValue object

(GetPropertyValue unboxObject "id") |> unbox;
```

It works, but isn't that too much overkill, especially when there could be large amount of data??

Comment: Dotnet uses [nominal type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) instead of  [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) which means that even if two classes have same shape, they're actually different. So you have to either write conversion manually or use AutoMapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this. Let's say you have C# code like this:

```
public class A {
  public static List<object> GetThings() {
    var a = new List<object>();
    a.Add(new { foo=1, bar="hi" });
    return a;
  }
}
```

As noted in the comments, .NET uses nominal typing so even though you never name the type, the C# compiler generates some name for it. In this case, the type of the actual objects in the list will be some private type with an ugly mangled name. You can find out what this is by using decompiler tools like `ildasm` and, in my case, this was something like `` <>f__AnonymousType0`2 ``.

It turns out you can even try using this from F#:

```
A.GetThings() |> Seq.map (fun a -> 
  let it = unbox<``<>f__AnonymousType0`2``<int, string>> a
  it )
```

The IDE knows about this type and it even tells you what its members are, but unfortunately (or maybe fortunately...), the type is marked as `private` and so this gives you an error:

> error FS1092: The type '<>f__AnonymousType0' is not accessible from this code location